# Spring Bean with the availability during the runtime of ApplicationServer

Tags: spring-mvc, thread-safety

I need to declare a Spring bean using Annotation-based config, which will be available throughout the runtime of the Application Server (in my case, JBoss). I should be able to write and read the data to/from the bean across multiple requests. I have read about the global session scoped bean, but couldn't find any concrete examples. Is there a way to implement this and what are the thread-safety concerns with this kind of bean?

Best Regards,
Chandra.